# Links from an external page (other web sites except search engines)

Tags: backlinks, cpanel, awstats

While checking metrics in cPanel like visitors, Awstats, and Webalizer, I find tons of Links from an external page (other web sites except search engines).

*Questions is, are they links countable in search engines? Should I take a headache on them or leave them alone?*

[image: Here's a screenshot; just a few days' glimpse in this month]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very doubt this bunch of russian backlinks will be countable by Google, supposing you aren't acting on russian market. I rather think such links are the first disavow candidate. It could be a kind of negative SEO attack, or a slightly unsmart approach to build backlinks.

In any case note the most important thing about backlinks: best backlink is the clicked one. No clicks is a sign of non-relevancy. I would disavow them all and sleep good.

Comment: Keep in mind that Russian spam links are not intended for Google per se' but for Russian search engines which are far less sophisticated and hence why we see them so often. They are annoying to be sure! Cheers!!

Comment: yeah..these are so persistent. Thanks so much.